# is this a safe assumption of normality and linearity? Anova/Linear Model (with code and example)

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, regression, distributions

I fitted a linear model (estimated using OLS) to predict T1_var with two factors : Phenotype (Control and PD), Condition (Treated, Not treated)

```
LM.fit <- lm(sqrt(T1_var) ~ Phenotype*Condition, data = 
            dat_animal_model_wide)
par(mfrow = c(1,2), las = 1)
hist(residuals(LM.fit), xlab = "residuals", ylab = "density",
     cex.main = 1, cex.axis = .9,
     main = "Histogram of residuals", proba = TRUE)
qqnorm(residuals(LM.fit), cex.main = 1, cex.axis = .9, 
        main = "Normal Q-Q Plot", cex = .4)  
      qqline(resid(LM.fit))
```

[image]

[image]

**Can I say that the assumptions of normality and linearity are respected based on this figure?** It's "kind of" a Gaussian shape distribution no ? ...

PS: I did a square root transformation because it looks better with the sqrt ...

Context: I have a small size sample: 18 subjects (6 for Phenotype 1 and 12 for phenotype 2) but i don't want to use a non-parametric test (Kruskal-Wallis in my case) because it is not powerful at all ...

Comment: The Q-Q plot looks fine to me. But I'd want to inspect a residual-vs.-fitted plot as well.

Comment: @COOLSerdash I edited my question with the residual-vs.-fitted plot

Comment: Thank you. Linearity is not really of concern here because you have in essence a two-way ANOVA with no continuous predictors. I don't see anything obvious here that would worry me. Two levels of the interaction have larger residuals than the other two, but this is compatible with sampling variation with such a small sample size (only 3 in those combinations!).

Comment: Thank you @COOLSerdash I am reassured to keep the two-way Anova instead of using a non-parametric test !